# mac run deepfakes - faceswap ' faceswap.py' get error

Tags: python, tensorflow

[project-github](https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap)

- macOS-10.14.2
- pyenv+python3.5
- tf-1.13.1

  1. 'python setup.py' (no docker,no CUDA)

$ python setup.py

WARNING Running without root/admin privileges
INFO    The tool provides tips for installation
        and installs required python packages
INFO    Setup in Darwin 18.2.0
INFO    Installed Python: 3.5.0 64bit
INFO    Encoding: UTF-8
INFO    Upgrading pip...
INFO    Installed pip: 19.0.3
Enable  Docker? [y/N] n
INFO    Docker Disabled
Enable  CUDA? [Y/n] n
INFO    CUDA Disabled
INFO    Checking System Dependencies...
INFO    CMake version: 3.14.1
Please ensure your System Dependencies are met. Continue? [y/N] y
INFO    All python3 dependencies are met.
        You are good to go.

```
    Enter:  'python faceswap.py -h' to see the options
            'python faceswap.py gui' to launch the GUI
```

2. then run this get error:

```sh
$ python faceswap.py -h
```

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "faceswap.py", line 5, in <module>
    import lib.cli as cli
  File "/Users/water/Desktop/git/other/faceswap/lib/cli.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lib.logger import crash_log, log_setup
  File "/Users/water/Desktop/git/other/faceswap/lib/logger.py", line 15, in <module>
    from lib.sysinfo import sysinfo
  File "/Users/water/Desktop/git/other/faceswap/lib/sysinfo.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lib.gpu_stats import GPUStats
  File "/Users/water/Desktop/git/other/faceswap/lib/gpu_stats.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pynvx  # pylint: disable=import-error
  File "/Users/water/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynvx/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _pynvx import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/water/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pynvx.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyThreadState_UncheckedGet
  Referenced from: /Users/water/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pynvx.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/water/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pynvx.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

Answer (score 0):

it work after change python from v3.5.0 to v3.6.8 , but i found the README said "Python >= 3.2-3.6 64-bit (cannot be 3.7.x as Tensorflow has not been updated to provide support)",so.